# Program breaks when character is entered instead of integer

Tags: c++, character, exit, cin

I'm new to C++ and am finding it difficult to find information on the cin feature. This is my first program ever so it's very simple. It determines if the entered number is a prime number or composite whilst filtering out bad values such as negative numbers and decimals. The program also will time-out after 10 failed entries.

The last feature I want to add to this program is the ability to filter out character inputs but I'm having no luck with trying different solutions. I tried converting the character to a float/double/int but to no avail. I just need help with cin, if the user inputs the letter 'K' or any other invalid character i'd like the program to recognize this and then produce the "invalid value" cout message + new entry try x number of times.

Currently when a character is entered the program crashes and goes through all 10 try attempts at once leaving the output results in the terminal very sloppy.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std ;

int main (void)
{
    //Declare variables
    int y, c, i1 ;
    double i ;

     //Ask for user input
     cout << endl << endl << "Please enter a number: " ;
     cin >> i ;

     //Eliminate bad user input values
     i1 = i ;

    //Detect when a decimal number is entered for the first attempt
    for ( c = 1 ; int(i1) != i ; c ++ )
    {
        cout << endl << "This value is invalid. Please retry: " ;
        cin >> i ;

         i1 = i ;

            //Terminate program after so many failed attempts
            if ( 8 < c )
            {
                cout << endl << "This value is invalid. Try again next time! \n\n" ;
                return 0 ;
            }

        //Detect if a '0' is entered on the latter attempts
        for ( c ; i < 1 ; c ++ )
        {
            cout << endl << "This value is invalid. Please retry: " ;
            cin >> i ;

            i1 = i ;

            //Terminate program after so many failed attempts
            if ( 8 < c )
            {
                cout << endl << "This value is invalid. Try again next time! \n\n" ;
                return 0 ;
            }
        }
    }

    //Detect when '0' is entered on the first attempt
    for ( c = 1 ; i < 1 ; c ++ )
    {
        cout << endl << "This value is invalid. Please retry: " ;
        cin >> i ;

         i1 = i ;

            //Terminate program after so many failed attempts
            if ( 8 < c )
            {
                cout << endl << "This value is invalid. Try again next time! \n\n" ;
                return 0 ;
            }

         //Detect if a decimal number is entered on the latter attempts
         for ( c ; int(i1) != i ; c ++ )

        {
            cout << endl << "This value is invalid. Please retry: " ;
            cin >> i ;

             i1 = i ;


            //Terminate program after so many failed attempts
            if ( 8 < c )
            {
                cout << endl << "This value is invalid. Try again next time! \n\n" ;
                return 0 ;
            }
        }
    }


     //Find prime numbers
    for ( y = 1 ; y <= i ; y ++ )
    {
        //Give instant result if user input is no. 1
        if ( i == 1 )
        {
            cout << endl << "The number: " << i << " is a composite number.\n\n" ;
            break ;
        }

        //Eliminate no. 1 from prime number search
        if ( y == 1 )
            continue ;

        //Search for a whole number division using modulus
        if ( fmod(i, y) == 0 )
        {
            if ( i == y )
                cout << endl << "The number: " << i << " is a prime number.\n\n" ;

            else if ( i != y )
            {   
                cout << endl << "The number: " << i << " is a composite number.\n\n" ;
                break ;
            }
        }   
    }   

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: `int main (void)` Why the C style function declaration in a C++ program?

Comment: Recommendation: If you know the program fails early, back up the code and remove everything after the failure point so you can focus on the problem. I also recommend  adding to the question sample input that you will reliably break the program

Comment: Recommendation: Always check the IO for success.`cin >> i ;` can fail without giving you ANY value to work with. You do not check for this case. You want something like `if (cin >> i) { use i } else { clear stream error flags and remove bad input }`

Comment: Note: `double` values are imprecise. For example, what you think is 5 might really be represented as 4.999999997, making it hard to use them in operations that require exact equality.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl I was told that it's just good practice to put void in-between the parenthesis if the program isn't going to return a value. I'm not 100% on it though.

Comment: `void` as denoting "no arguments" is correct C, but redundant (and weird) in C++. Remember; they are *very* different languages.

Comment: Explicitly stating `void` for an empty parameter list is more style issue these days than anything else. If the parameter list is empty, it's already obvious that no parameters are required. You gain nothing. The ability to do this exists to make it easier for a C++ compiler to parse C code, something that is still relatively easy to do, but getting more difficult to do as C and C++ drift further apart.

Comment: "put void in-between the parenthesis if the program isn't going to return a value" that's not at all what's going on here. `main` returns `int` regardless of your `void`. You are mixing up function arguments and return value.